# How to get IntelliSense to recognize macro arguments in C?

Tags: c, macros, intellisense

When I write out this function in VS Code:

```
/**
 * Prints the number passed in to error output.
 *  @param number The number to print
 *  @return void
 */
void print_num_error(int number);
```

IntelliSense works as normal:
[image: IntelliSense working as normal]

However, when I write out the same function as a macro:

```
/**
 * Prints the number passed in to error output.
 *  @param number The number to print
 *  @return void
 */
#define print_num_error(number) fprintf(stderr,"%d",number)
```

IntelliSense then does not recognize the macro arguments: [image: IntelliSense bean dumb]

Is there something that I can do to make IntelliSense recognize the macro parameters, or is this simply not possible with IntelliSense?

Comment: What if you put in a dummy parameter?

Comment: Add doxygen comment and VS code will understand it

Comment: @tadman What do you mean by that?

Comment: What I mean is the macro use might not be fully recognized since there are no arguments given. `x(y)` and `x()` are syntactically different.

Comment: @tadman I tried `int y = 5; print_num_error(y);`, and nothing changed.

Comment: It's worth noting that in modern C the difference between a macro and a function is often pretty thin, as the compiler can and will inline what you write if it can. Is using a function for this a deal-breaker?

Comment: @tadman Unfortunately yes. The macro I specified is a little different from what I am intending to use this for, and some other macros I need it for use macro-specific features I cannot replicate in functions.